# Concyclic points on a circle

Tags: geometry, contest-math, euclidean-geometry, circles

This is a question I met in some notes. I need some help here.

> Let $ABC$ be an acute triangle and let $AA_1, BB_1, CC_1$ be its altitudes. Segments $AA_1$ and $B_1C_1$ meet at $K$. The perpendicular bisector of segment $A_1K$ intersects sides $AB$ and $AC$ at $L$ and $M$ respectively. Prove that points $A, A_1, L$ and $M$ lie on a circle.

Can anyone help?

Comment: try to draw it. I am not sure it is true.

Comment: @Moti It is. Use GeoGebra to verify it.

Comment: My error. ill look again.

Comment: You could try proving that K is the orthocentre of ΔALM. This can be done simply by showing that LK || BB₁. I believe that this can be done using trigonometry. Nevertheless, doing this will complete the proof since A₁ is the reflection of K over LM.

Comment: @SharvLaad Can you be more specific about the "showing that LK || BB₁ using trigonometry" part? Thank you

Comment: Yes. I’m not sure it will work as I haven’t done it myself. But my approach would be as follows. To find AK/KH where H is the orthocentre, use sine rule in triangles AB₁K and HB₁K. To find AL/BL, we have by BPT, AL/BL = AT/A₁T (where T is the midpoint of A₁K) = (AK+KT)/A₁T = 1 + AK/A₁T = 1 + 2AK/A₁K. AK/A₁K can be found by sine rule in AB₁A₁.

Comment: You should find that AL/BL = AK/KH

Answer (score 0):

For reasons of (parallel lines, angles in the same segment, and properties of orthic triangle), all the blue marked angles are equal. In particular $\phi = \phi’$.

[image]

Let LM meet $BB_1$ at N’, and $CC_1$ at N. Since LN’NM is the perpendicular bisector of $KA_1$, a circle can be drawn through K, **L**, $A_1$ with its diameter being part of LM. $\angle LC_1N = 90^{\circ}$ confirms that LN is its diameter.

Added: A circle passing through $K, L, A_1$ can definitely be formed. Note that  LM is the perpendicular bisector of $KA_1$. This means the center of that circle is somewhere on LM. This also means the diameter of that circle lies on LM. By converse of "angles in semi-circle", if $\angle LC_1N = 90^{\circ}$, then LN is the diameter of that circle.

This means N, K, $C_1$, L, $A_1$ are con-cyclic. Therefore, $\phi’’ = \phi = \phi’$.

Required result follows.

Comment: You said "$∠LC_1N=90^0$  confirms that LN is its diameter." But don't you need to know that either $L$ or $C_1$ is on the circle for it to work? Thanks

Comment: @user532908 I made a minor mistake. It should be "a circle can be drawn through $K, L, A_1$" instead (of $K, N, A_1$). See additional explanation in the added part.

Comment: Thanks @Mick But I still don't get a point. Why $C_1$? How can you be so sure that $C_1$ is on the circle? Only if $C_1$ is on the circle then you can say that $N$ is on the circle right?

Comment: And can you explain the "For reasons of (parallel lines, angles in the same segment, and properties of orthic triangle)" part?

Comment: @user532908 1) I will skip the // lines part. 2a) $\angle B_1B A_1 = \phi’$ because $ABA_1B_1$ is cyclic. 2b) Similarly, $\phi = \omega$; where $\omega$ is the blue angle next to $\phi$. 3) The feet of the altitudes of any triangle form a special triangle (called orthic). Its properties is “if H is the ortho-center of $\triangle ABC$, then H is also the in-center of $\triangle A_1B_1C_1$”. IE, $\omega = \phi$; 4) From the previous comment, L is one end of the diameter of circle $KLA_1$. Since $\angle LC_1N$ is right-angled with N lands somewhere on LM, LN has to be the diameter of that circle.

Comment: I believe it still needs to be proved that $C_1$ is on the circle $KLA_1$.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

In a triangle $ABC$ with orthocenter $H$, $h_a = a/(\cot \beta + \cot \gamma)$ and $AH = a \cot \alpha$.

From $h_c/AC_1 = h_b/AB_1 = \tan \alpha$ and $c h_c = b h_b$, we have $\triangle AB_1C_1 \sim \triangle ABC$. Then, from $AC_1/AH = \cos \alpha_1$ and from $\triangle AKC_1$,
$$\frac {AK} {\sin \gamma} =
\frac {AC_1} {\sin(\gamma + \alpha_1)} =
\frac {AH \sin \beta} {\sin \gamma \sin \beta + \cos \gamma \cos \beta}, \\
AK = \frac {a \cot \alpha} {1 + \cot \beta \cot \gamma}.$$
From $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle ALM$,
$$\frac {LM} a = \frac {AN} {h_a} = \frac {(h_a + AK)/2} {h_a} =
\frac 1 2 \left( 1 -
 \frac {\cot(\beta +\gamma)(\cot \beta + \cot \gamma)}
  {1 + \cot \beta \cot \gamma} \right) =
\frac 1 {1 + \cot \beta \cot \gamma}, \\
AK = LM \cot \alpha.$$
Therefore, $K$ is the orthocenter of $\triangle ALM$. Since $AC'KB'$ is cyclic and $\angle C'KB' = \angle LA_1M$, $ALA_1M$ is also cyclic.